# Solving for y parameters using a system of equations

Tags: s-parameters

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVLuuz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Question: Find the y parameters for the circuit shown below.

My attempt:

KCL

\$I_1 = I_3 + I_6 \$

\$I_4 = I_3 + I_5\$

\$I_5 = I_2 + I_6\$

EFC:

\$I_3 = \frac{V_1 - V_a}{20}\$

\$I_4 = \frac{V_a-0}{10}\$

\$I_5 = \frac{V_2 - V_a}{4}\$

\$I_6 = \frac{V_1 - V_2}{8}\$

Solving this systems for \$ V_1 \$ and \$ V_2\$ yields:

\$ V_1 = \frac{35}{2} + \frac{25}{2} \$

\$ V_2 = \frac{25 }{2} + \frac{27}{2} \$

Therefore our Z parameters are as follows:

\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{35}{2} & \frac{25}{2} \\
\frac{25}{2} & \frac{27}{2}
  \end{bmatrix}

I know how to find the y parameters using delta Z, but I thought there was a way to solve for these items directly in the system of equations. Can I solve for the y parameters directly?

Comment: y-parameters is just admittance instead of impedance, so ofcourse it is possible. But why do it if its easier for you to find the z parameters first, and then convert it?

Comment: @Linkyyy I solved it this way as it was the only way I knew how. I would rather solve for y instead of z in the system of equations

Comment: @Linkyyy are you saying, in general, it is easier to do it the way I'm doing it now?

Comment: Look up the definition of y parameters, and you will see that it is not that dificult when you already understand what z parameters is. The difference is you short the opposite port, instead of having it open circuited. Then you calculate the admittance instead of the impedance (which is really just the reciprocal of each other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint: \$ Y_{11} = \frac{I_1}{V_1} \$ when you short-circuit \$ V_2 \$.
 This arises from \$ I_1 = V_1 Y_{11} + V_2 Y_{12} \$. The short-circuited \$ V_2 \$ forces the \$V_2 Y_{12} \$ term to zero.

The other equation that applies is \$ I_2 = V_1 Y_{21} + V_2 Y_{22} \$ .

Somehow, you just memorize these (they're burned into my non-volatile-memory). The other aid to memory is visualization of a current source in parallel with a conductance: one for input port and another for output port. Another aid to sanity-check your memory is to verify **units**. For Y-parameters, units must be in terms of *conductance* and/or *susceptance*....like a current divided by a voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHWE8G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You seem to be more familiar with Z-parameters. Here, units are *resistance*, and instead of current sources, you have two voltage sources, with series-resistors. Of course, you could solve the Z-parameter equations, then transform the four parameters into Y-parameters, but that's a bit round-about.